# Codeigniter error while connecting two database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

From last 5 hours i am stuck with the below  warning and error i am trying to connect with two database in my project and all was working fine when using the windows pc now i have shifted to mac and i am getting the below warning while connecting the code is same

> A PHP Error was encountered
>   Severity: Warning
>
> Message: mysqli::real_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: 
>              getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
>
> Filename: mysqli/mysqli_driver.php
>       Line Number: 202
>       Backtrace:
>       File: 
>       /Library/WebServer/Documents/project/application/core/BaseController.php
>       Line: 18
>       Function: __construct
>
> File: /Library/WebServer/Documents/project/application/controllers/User.php
>       Line: 11
>       Function: __construct
>
> File: /Library/WebServer/Documents/project/index.php
>       Line: 296
>       Function: require_once

In my Base controller i am loading the second db
        $this->db2 = $this->load->database('abc',TRUE);
As far i understand its not about the issue of connecting the databse as if it was then on my index page its should have shown error as i am initializing the db in my base controller i am really stuck in this pls help me out

Comment: It can't find your hostname, whatever that is, so check your configuration for what database server you're connecting to.

Comment: Try switching to ip-defined DB connections.

Comment: Ditto @tadman. Try replacing your database host with the IP address of the database directly (or 127.0.0.1 if it's local). If it then works, you'll want to adjust DNS settings accordingly.

Comment: hostname is localhost and first db its connecting to that and changed localhost  to 127.0.0.1 but no luck

Comment: Maybe thsi would be simpler if you just posted the relevant config file for us to check

Comment: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/connecting.html#manually-connecting-to-a-database